# How can I change data type of a DataGridView's column to CheckBox?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagrid

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from mytable", con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds.Clear();
da.Fill(ds);

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.Columns["id"].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.Columns["chk"].HeaderText ="Check";
```

This did not work:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["chk"].CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
```

Comment: the DataType of your Field should be `bit`, so you don't need to create a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`, if am correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an actual checkbox column:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
```